# arabic character viewing during runtime

Tags: asp.net, html, encoding, telerik, arabic

I face the following problem :
when i copy a specific page to my new solution :

in run time i get this !!

[image]

although it 's like this in the design time :

[image]

my .aspx :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

i try to use  `charset=iso-8859-6` instead but the same problem !!
How to fix this problem and why this happens ?

Comment: what encoding is detected by the browser? (View->Character Encoding in FF)

Comment: check this http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/125320-arabic-asp

Comment: hmmmm the grid arabic letters appear correctly , the problem only with gridview header and the header of the page !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several tries i just change the charset to `windows-1252` and every thing goes okay.

Like this:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> i try to use charset=iso-8859-6 instead but the same problem !!

That means your server is sending an actual Content-Type header with a charset. The `<meta>`-tag is secondary to an actual header.

You can do that using:

```
<%@ Page ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

or

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

But don't just hack blindly, it is easy to use Google Chrome developer tools (or whatever you prefer) to see what header your server sends:

[image]